# Instagram API docs invalid JSON error

Tags: python, json, instagram, instagram-api

I keep getting this error when I tried the examples in the [python-instagram](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram#using-an-access-token) documentation:

```
from instagram.client import InstagramAPI

access_token = "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN"
client_secret = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET"
api = InstagramAPI(access_token=access_token, client_secret=client_secret)
recent_media, next_ = api.user_recent_media(user_id="userid", count=10)
for media in recent_media:
   print media.caption.text
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 197, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 189, in execute
    content, next = self._do_api_request(url, method, body, headers)
  File "/Users/bli1/Development/Django/CL/cherngloong/cherngloong/lib/python2.7/site-packages/instagram/bind.py", line 131, in _do_api_request
    raise InstagramClientError('Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.', status_code=response['status'])
InstagramClientError: (404) Unable to parse response, not valid JSON.
```

I'm not sure what is causing this error. I got my `access_token` and filled in all the parameters

I get the same error when I try other parts of the documentation:

```
api = InstagramAPI(client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID', client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET')
popular_media = api.media_popular(count=20)
for media in popular_media:
    print media.images['standard_resolution'].url
```

Answer (score 0):

Ig made some major platform changes (introducing a Sandbox Mode) on Nov 17th that may be affecting your access.

I would check out [this thread](https://github.com/Instagram/python-instagram/issues/202), from the repo you are using, plenty of SO links there as well.

A suggestion would be to bypass the python API and use `curl` with something like this for writing a comment  (see if you can narrow down your error):

```
curl -F 'access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN' \
 -F 'text=This+is+my+comment' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/media/{media-id}/comments
```